# Adding data to Woocommerce admin order general details block

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

What is the name of the hook to add info after the General Details block in the upper left of a Woocommerce admin single order view? There's Billing Address and Shipping Address and then General Details on the left, which has Order Date and Order Status etc. I need to add a link below that, what is the hook, similar to woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address?

Answer (score 2):

Found it:  woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details